# app crash due to UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: in iOS 5.1 Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, loadnibnamed

Its works fine on iOS 6 simulator. On iOS 5.1 Simulator when i run it for the very first time it get crashed due to the following exception.

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'

Here's my code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    cell = [theTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"listTableCell" owner:self options:NULL];
        }
        else{
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"listTableCell_iPad" owner:self         options:NULL];
        }
        cell = nibLoadCellForListDetails;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

And in listTableCell.xib I set the File's Owner as my table view controller. And i made an outlet as nibLoadCellForListDetails in my table view controller correctly.

Comment: Are you using ARC? Are nibLoadCellForListDetails and cell vars weak or strong?

Comment: There are few thinks to check: check xib target dependencies, double check xib spelling and I suggest calling self.nibLoadCellForListDetails;

Comment: @MikhailVasilyev Ya i'm using ARC.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like no cell has actually been created. Add in:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

instead of:

```
cell = [theTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
```

Comment: ok its working but it displays empty cell in the tableview. It creates a default style cell. I want my custom style cell with three labels tagged 1,2,3 in my cell in the nib file.

Comment: "I can only show you the door. You're the one that has to walk through it."

Comment: the door is being locked. I wanna key to open it.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try like this

```
if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *nib;
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {

      nib =   [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"listTableCell" owner:self options:NULL];
    }
    else{
      nib =  [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"listTableCell_iPad" owner:self         options:NULL];
    }
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
```